# My SQLite database is not created when i open the app and it crashes

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, arraylist, hashmap

i am new to android and it seems that i am a favour of crashing any app i make :)

i am creating a simple contacts app where the user enters the contacts data by himself and then he can see them on a list view in the mainactivity

everytime i open the app it simply crashes, and when i look at my logcat i see that the database is not created, can anyone help me and tell me what am i doing wrong?

my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button ADD;
ListView LS;
DBcreator dbview;
SQLiteDatabase db;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> List = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();// define
                                                                                    // an
                                                                                    // arraylist
                                                                                    // with
                                                                                    // hashmap
                                                                                    // for
                                                                                    // ref.//

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ADD = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AddButton);
    LS = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ContactsList);
    SimpleAdapter sa = new SimpleAdapter(this, List,
            R.layout.activity_main, new String[] { DBcreator.KEY_ROWID,
                    DBcreator.KEY_FNAME, DBcreator.KEY_LNAME,
                    DBcreator.KEY_MOBILE, DBcreator.KEY_ADDRESS },
            new int[] { R.id.ContactsList });
    existingcontacts();
    LS.setAdapter(sa);
    LS.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    ADD.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent j = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CreateContact.class);
            startActivity(j);
        }
    });
}

private void existingcontacts() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    DBcreator db = new DBcreator(MainActivity.this);
    SQLiteDatabase database = db.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor find = database.rawQuery("select * from contactsdisplay", null);
    while (find.moveToNext()) {
        HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
        data.put("_ID", find.getString(0));
        data.put("FirstName", find.getString(1));
        data.put("LastName", find.getString(2));
        data.put("Mobile", find.getString(3));
        data.put("Address", find.getString(4));
        List.add(data);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

the Database Class:

```
public class DBcreator extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
/*
 * this class is responsible for all the database manipulation and
 * requirements it is called inside other classes for implementation
 */
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contacts";// NAME OF THE
                                                        // DATABASE//
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "contactsdisplay";// NAME OF
                                                                    // THE
                                                                    // TABLE
                                                                    // INSIDE
                                                                    // OF
                                                                    // IT//
// THE DATA INSIDE THE TABLE//
public static final String KEY_FNAME = "first_name";
public static final String KEY_LNAME = "last_name";
public static final String KEY_MOBILE = "mobile";
public static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
// VERSION OF THE DATABASE//
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
// create database//
public static final String DATABASE_CREATE = " CREATE TABLE "
        + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" + KEY_ROWID
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_FNAME
        + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_LNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_MOBILE
        + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_ADDRESS + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

public DBcreator(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);// this orders the code to create the
                                // database//

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // drop old version and use the new one//
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
    onCreate(db);

}

public long add(String fname, String lname, String mob, String address) {
    // getting the database and editing in it//
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    // insert what the user had entered in the database//
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_FNAME, fname);
    cv.put(KEY_LNAME, lname);
    cv.put(KEY_MOBILE, mob);
    cv.put(KEY_ADDRESS, address);
    // db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

}

public void savechanges(String fname, String lname, String mob,
        String address) {
    // change the existing data of the contact by lookup then replace//
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] array = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_FNAME, KEY_LNAME,
            KEY_MOBILE, KEY_ADDRESS };
    Cursor c = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, array, fname, null, null, null,
            null);
    // we need to loop inside the database to find the existing values and
    // replace them//
    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        int firstname = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_FNAME);
        int lastname = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_FNAME);
        int mobile = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_FNAME);
        int address2 = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_FNAME);
        if (c.getString(firstname).equals(fname)) {
            ContentValues changes = new ContentValues();
            changes.put(KEY_FNAME, fname);
            changes.put(KEY_LNAME, lname);
            changes.put(KEY_MOBILE, mob);
            changes.put(KEY_ADDRESS, address);
            db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, changes, KEY_FNAME + "=" + fname,
                    null);
            break;
        }
    }
}

public void deletecontact(String fnamedelete) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_FNAME + "=" + fnamedelete, null);
}

public String[] queryall() {
    String[] FirstNames = new String[] { KEY_FNAME };
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cfname = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, FirstNames, null, null, null,
            null, null);// to see all contacts//
    int GetTheName = cfname.getColumnIndex(KEY_FNAME);
    List<String> TheNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    {

        cfname.moveToFirst();
        while (cfname.moveToNext()) {
            TheNames.add(cfname.getString(GetTheName));

        }
        return TheNames.toArray(new String[TheNames.size()]);
    }

}

}
```

the Logcat:

```
 01-04 15:59:38.294: E/Trace(7479): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-04 15:59:38.518: W/dalvikvm(7479): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41af8908)
01-04 15:59:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(7479): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-04 15:59:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(7479): java.lang.IllegalStateException: android.widget.ListView is not a  view that can be bounds by this SimpleAdapter
01-04 15:59:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(7479):     at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.bindView(SimpleAdapter.java:195)
01-04 15:59:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(7479):     at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.createViewFromResource(SimpleAdapter.java:126)
01-04 15:59:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(7479):     at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getView(SimpleAdapter.java:114)
01-04 15:59:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(7479):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2340)
01-04 15:59:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(7479):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1250)
01-04 15:59:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(7479):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1162)
01-04 15:59:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(7479):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15341)
01-04 15:59:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(7479):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:602)
01-04 15:59:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(7479):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:415)
01-04 15:59:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(7479):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15341)
01-04 15:59:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(7479):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4931)
01-04 15:59:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(7479):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-04 15:59:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(7479):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15341)
01-04 15:59:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(7479):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
01-04 15:59:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(7479):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
01-04 15:59:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(7479):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15341)
01-04 15:59:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(7479):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4931)
01-04 15:59:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(7479):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-04 15:59:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(7479):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2172)
01-04 15:59:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(7479):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15341)
01-04 15:59:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(7479):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2131)
01-04 15:59:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(7479):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1242)
01-04 15:59:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(7479):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1435)
01-04 15:59:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(7479):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1127)
01-04 15:59:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(7479):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4606)
01-04 15:59:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(7479):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:747)
01-04 15:59:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(7479):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:567)
01-04 15:59:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(7479):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:536)
01-04 15:59:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(7479):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:733)
01-04 15:59:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(7479):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-04 15:59:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(7479):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-04 15:59:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(7479):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
01-04 15:59:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(7479):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5006)
01-04 15:59:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(7479):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-04 15:59:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(7479):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-04 15:59:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(7479):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
01-04 15:59:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(7479):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
01-04 15:59:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(7479):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You probably want to inter change this  `DATABASE_NAME = "contacts";`  `DATABASE_TABLE = "contactsdisplay.db"`

Comment: i dont understand why should i do this?...shouldnt i refer to the file ad database through writinh contactsdisplay.db?

Comment: `contacts` is the table so it should be the `DATABASE_TABLE`. contactsdisplay.db` is the database name so it should be `DATABASE_NAME`. This has nothing to do with the error though

Comment: well i would like to solve the main problem...i dont think that this will change much as now it sees that Contacts is the database name and the table inside it is contactsdisplay......any ideas on the main problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In onCreate you're creating a table that is called contactsdisplay.db (you shoudn't probably end table names with .db, it's confusing).

And from this line:  `Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: data (code 1): , while compiling: select * from data`

cause by this line:

`Cursor find = database.rawQuery("select * from data", null);` you are accessing the table "data" that is never created.

**EDIT:** in this line:

```
SimpleAdapter sa = new SimpleAdapter(this, List,  R.layout.activity_main ...)
```

The third argument has to be a resource for the actual ListView **item**.

Comment: thx man but i changed both and put the cursor as below                    Cursor find = database.rawQuery("select * from contactsdisplay", null); but still it is crashing and no file created

Comment: well can you repaste the edited code and stacktrace? I'm not psychic. :)

Comment: Done what? Edit your original post and show the changes and the new error message. :)

Comment: i did that...not much of a change and the same log applies....i added the changes you suggested....look at the edit comment plz

Comment: In your post the error is still "no such table: data (code 1): ", I need to know the new error.

Comment: I've edited my answer, when creating the Adapter you need to specify the resource that corresponds to a single row of your ListView.

Comment: thx i found another way and used your answer partially and it works now...thx :)

Answer (score 0):

Heyy, your table name is wrong. Its `contactsdisplay.db` this is why the table is not found.

**Correction:** make the table name as `contactsdisplay`

**Note:** You dont have to mention `.db` extension when using `SQLiteOpenHelper` class.

Comment: @HossaTheCoder what error occurs after applying changes ? update your question.

Answer (score 0):

i made another xml to display the data and then i used a simple cursor as below

```
DBcreator db = new DBcreator(MainActivity.this);
        SQLiteDatabase database = db.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor find = database.rawQuery("select * from contactsdisplay", null);//go read from the database contactsdisplay//
        //below is the adapter to put the intended content in the list view//
        SimpleCursorAdapter cursor=new     SimpleCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                R.layout.listviewdistribution,
                find,
                new String[] {DBcreator.KEY_FNAME, DBcreator.KEY_LNAME,DBcreator.KEY_MOBILE,DBcreator.KEY_ADDRESS},
                new int[]{R.id.FirstNameTextView,R.id.LastNameTextView,R.id.MobileTextView,R.id.AddressTextView});
        //below is looping with the cursor inside the table to get all data//
        while (find.moveToNext()) {
            HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
            data.put("_ID", find.getString(0));
            data.put("FirstName", find.getString(1));
            data.put("LastName", find.getString(2));
            data.put("Mobile", find.getString(3));
            data.put("Address", find.getString(4));
            List.add(data);
        }
        LS.setAdapter(cursor);
    }
```